# Consolidate 10 bit Value into a Unique Byte

Tags: algorithm, binary, logic, byte

As part of an algorithm I'm writing, I need to find a way to convert a 10-bit word into a unique 8-bit word. The 10-bit word is made up of 5 pairs, where each pair can only ever equal 0, 1 or 2 (never 3). For example:

```
|00|10|00|01|10|
```

This value needs to somehow be consolidated into a single, unique byte.

As each pair can never equal 3, there are a wide range of values that this 10-bit word will never represent, which makes me think that it is possible to create an algorithm to perform this conversion. The simplest way to do this would be to use a lookup table, but it seems like a waste of resources to store ~680 values which will only be used once in my program. I've already tried to incorporate one of the pairs into the others somehow, but every attempt I've made has resulted in a non-unique value, and I'm now very quickly running out of ideas!

Any help?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'm programming this onto a microcontroller, so I need all the space I can save!!

Comment: Try Huffman coding -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number you have is essentially base 3. You just need to convert this to base 2.

There are 5 pairs, so 3^5 = 243 numbers. And 8 bits is 2^8 = 256 numbers, so it's possible.

The simplest way to convert between bases is to go to base 10 first.

So, for your example:

```
00|10|00|01|10

Base 3: 02012

Base 10: 2*3^3 + 1*3^1 + 2*3^0
       = 54 + 3 + 2
       = 59

Base 2:
    59 % 2 = 1
/2  29 % 2 = 1
/2  14 % 2 = 0
/2   7 % 2 = 1
/2   3 % 2 = 1
/2   1 % 2 = 1

   So 111011 is your number in binary
```

[This](http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/Num/conv.htm) explains the above process in a bit more detail.

Note that once you have `59` above stored in a 1-byte integer, you'll probably already have what you want, thus explicitly converting to base 2 might not be necessary.

Comment: Damn your quick fingers :)

Answer (score 1):

What you basically have is a base 3 number and you want to convert this to a single number 0 - 255, luckily 5 digits in ternary (base 3) gives 243 combinations.

What you'll need to do is:

```
Digit      Action
(  1st     x 3^4)
+ (2nd     x 3^3)
+ (3rd     x 3^2)
+ (4th     x 3)
+ (5th)
```

This will give you a number 0 to 242.

Answer (score 0):

You are considering to store some information in a byte. A byte can contain at most 2 ^ 8 = 256 status.

Your status is totally 3 ^ 5 = 243 < 256. That make the transfer possible.

Consider your pairs are ABCDE (each character can be 0, 1 or 2)

You can just calculate A*3^4 + B*3^3 + C*3^2 + D*3 + E as your result. I guarantee the result will be in range 0 -- 255.